# Edit only the first cell in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a gradient to the first cell in my `UITableView`.

Here is the `if` statement I use to determine if the cell is the first in the table.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
```

This code does not seem to be working as there are a few cells with the gradient, notably the first and last cell along with sometimes the second cell. This is rather odd as the information I am grabbing in the array using `indexPath.row` is getting the information from the correct position.

**Why is my if statement not working? Even though I am grabbing information from the correct location in the array.**

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to remove the gradient if its not the first cell because an issue that can arise is if a cell dequeued was originally the first cell, it will have the gradient

Comment: @Josh Hamet that should not cause an issue because the cells that are in my table remain in the same position. I have not had them change places.

Comment: Due to the fact that cells are reused for performance reasons, you _must_ handle the case for the other cells as well (for example, set the desired background color instead of the gradient)

Comment: I forgot about reusing them, that should fix the issue. I will test it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not implementing `prepareForReuse` in your custom UITableViewCell subclass.  It looks like you are correctly targeting the first cell, so perhaps when that cell is later reused for other index paths you aren't clearing the gradient you added earlier.

Comment: How do I override the `prepareForReuse` to make it so that the cell "resets" itself to a point before having an extra layer added?

Comment: @brettf Hard to say for sure without seeing your code, but my first thought is that your custom cell should have an ivar that references the gradient layer that it inserts.  In the `prepareForReuse` method, it would do something like `self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()`.  For this to work, your UITableViewDataSource should only call a method on the custom cell, like `showGradient()`, rather than inserting the layer from outside the custom cell class.  If the custom cell class manages inserting the gradient layer itself, it can also keep a reference to it and remove it when being reused.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an `else` condition to go along with your `if`. Because table view cells are reused, you need to make sure to remove the gradient if it is in a cell other than the first one.

```
if(first cell)
   add gradient
else
   remove gradient if it exists
```

Comment: How would I go about removing the gradient sublayer?

Comment: @brettf without knowing how you set it up in the first place, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using custom cells, set the custom cell gradient variable to clear colour on all but the first cell.
2. If you're using standard uitableview cells, add the gradient to every cell as default and then if it's your first cell change the gradient colours to whatever you need it to be, and clear colour as default.
3. Alternatively clean all subviews from the cell after allocating it like this:

   for (UIView * sub in cell.subviews){
      [sub removeFromSuperview];
   }

Then add your gradient for the first cell.

Option 1 is the cleanest.